# WPF ActualWidth is zero

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, layout, actualwidth

I have a user control which has a `Canvas` of height 100 and width 1920.

At the loading of the control, I go to an external source, download a text file and add `TextBlock`s to the Canvas. Then I want to create a marquee scrolling effect which should work just fine, except after I add the `TextBlock`s to the `Canvas`, I need to get their width for calculation purposes but the `ActualWidth` property is always zero.

Here is some code:

```
private readonly LinkedList<TextBlock> textBlocks = new LinkedList<TextBlock>();

public LocalNewsControl()
{
    Loaded += LocalNewsControlLoaded;
}

private void LocalNewsControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadDataContext();
}

private void LoadDataContext()
{
    DataContext = new NewsItemsViewModel((exception) => LoadNewsItems());
}

private void LoadNewsItems()
{
    var viewModel = (NewsItemsViewModel)DataContext;

    NewsCanvas.Children.Clear();
    textBlocks.Clear();

    foreach (var newsViewModel in viewModel.NewsItems)
    {
        var tb = new TextBlock
        {
            Text = newsViewModel.Headline,
            FontSize = 28,
            FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal,
            Foreground = Brushes.Black
        };

        NewsCanvas.Children.Add(tb);

        Canvas.SetTop(tb, 20);
        Canvas.SetLeft(tb, -999);

        textBlocks.AddLast(tb);
    }

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        var node = textBlocks.First;

        while (node != null)
        {
            if (node.Previous != null)
            {
                //THIS IS WHERE ActualWidth is always ZERO
                var left = Canvas.GetLeft(node.Previous.Value) + node.Previous.Value.ActualWidth + Gap;
                Canvas.SetLeft(node.Value, left);
            }
            else
                Canvas.SetLeft(node.Value, NewsCanvas.Width + Gap);

            node = node.Next;
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: TextBlock isn't visible and isn't loaded so it hasn't a property ActualWidth. I've solved a similar problem with Itemscontrol, but i'm not sure about Canvas. Try events like LayoutUpdated, SizeChanged and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick with your dispatcher call - set the priority to loaded then it will be called same time as the loaded event and you should have a value.
There is an overload on BeginInvoke that takes a priority also.

Answer (score 5):

You could always attach a delgate to the `PropertyMetatdata/OnValueChanged` and when `ActualHeight/ActualWidth` changes from 0 to something, adjust your scrolling, `ActualWidth/ActualHeight` will have a value once its rendered at least once:

```
LocalNewsControl()
{
    var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ActualWidthProperty, typeof(TextBlock));
    if (descriptor != null)
        descriptor.AddValueChanged(myTextBlock, ActualWidth_ValueChanged);
}

private void ActualWidth_ValueChanged(object a_sender, EventArgs a_e)
{
   //Modify you scroll things here
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any `Control`'s `ActualHeight` or `ActualWidth` will always be zero before they are `Loaded` > `Measured` > `Arranged` > `Rendered`.

In your case, I recommend using `Loaded` or `SizeChanged` event of that `TextBlock` to your advantage.

Comment: there are many many textblocks though, I would have to subscribe to the Loaded event of the last one added which seems like a bit of a hack dont you think?

Comment: I guess you are right! Unless you add these `TextBlock` controls in a `StackPanel` with `Horizontal` orientation and scroll that panel. In that case, you would have to deal with that `Panel`'s events only.

Comment: A Control is rendered first before its Loaded event is called.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason for using `Canvas` for the layout of the `TextBlock`s? If not, you'd better use a `StackPanel` with Horizontal orientation, it will handle the layout math for you.

Comment: im doing a scrolling marquee effect which means that each item really needs to be individual and positioned absolutely on the canvas